# Is the complete SO rendering JS available uncompressed?

Tags: support, markdown, editor

I have a blog which I've started working on for the first time in a while, and I can't help but notice how often I want to use the SO markup. I don't just mean `prettify`, I mean using `, __, and * as well. It looks like that is really just a JS overlay so that the processing is done on the client side, but all of the JS on SO is minified. Is this an open library, or do I just need to learn to change how I type again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We (I say we, but most credit goes to the original WMD and [balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha)) have open sourced the javascript version of our Markdown renderer as [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown), available on Google Code.

It does not include our extensions to the Markdown spec.  Most of them don't make sense outside of our network.

Comment: AWESOME. Thank you so much. This has been driving me nuts.

Comment: @Kevin, Is there no chance of getting the spoiler extension? I could see that one being very useful outside the network.

Comment: @Brandon What is the spoiler extension?

Comment: @Ethan, `>!` blockquote syntax with an exclamation mark.